# How to check if mysqli_query deleted any rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created function that delete some data from my database. This is part of it:

```
mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM appsdata WHERE ownerID=123");
```

But I want to check how many rows were deleted. Mysql_query returns always true, no matter if something was deleted :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `mysqli_affected_rows`:

```
mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli_link);
```

or

```
$mysqli->affected_rows
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: what is "$mysqli_link"?

Comment: In Your case it would be "$con".